# Informatica - Number Datatype issue

Tags: informatica

I am loading data from flat-file to oracle table.
In flat-file I have a field, which holds the value like `"871685900000027865"` and its datatype in `SourceQualifier` is Decimal.

[image]

But in oracle target it is loading as

```
"8.71685900000003E17"
```

[image]

While running Debugger, I found out that, In the Source Qualifier itself data is changed to exponential form.

Please suggest an easy approach to load data as it is into target.

[Client Screenshot For reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2W8g.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Enable High Precision" session property.

I'd also add that in the Flat File it's a string. Flat files do not have any datatype definititions - these are just flat text files. So once you've specified Decimal in Source Qualifier, it tries to do the conversion for you. And with High Precision not enabled, it will use the exponential form. This is by design.

But again: what you get from DB strictly depends on the table definition and client tool that you're using. Can you share or check the table definition? If the column is decimal, it should not store data in this form.

Comment: Thanks @Maciejg. In target table definition,Column is in decimal and we are using informatica 9.6

Comment: "Enable High Precision" are also enabled and in target table definition,Column is in decimal.In source Now I changed to STRING, still I am getting the issue.

Comment: What tool are you using to query Oracle? Can you cast the value to varchar with the select statement? It's quite possible, that due to the length of the number, the client tool converts the value and only >presents< it in scientific notation, whlie it's being kept as decimal in database. Casting to varchar should prove it.

Comment: I am using PL/SQL developer tool.And It is true as you said, I have to cast to value to varchar to get right information.